# Laravel: How can I set dynamic table headers from a nested foreach loop?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I have this markup in my blade template:

```
<th>Name</th>
    @foreach($camp->athletes as $athlete)
        @foreach($athlete->kickoffs as $key=>$kickoff)
            <th>D#{{ ($key+1) }}</th>
            <th>H#{{ ($key+1) }}</th>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
<th>Avg. Distance</th>
<th>Avg. Hang Time</th>
<th>Score</th>
```

Which works fantastic when I only have a single athlete. But, when I start adding more, it's obvious that I am going to repeat the `<th>` elements for each athlete. Something like this is what I am getting:

```
<th>D#1</th>
<th>H#1</th>
<th>D#2</th>
<th>H#2</th>

<th>D#1</th>
<th>H#1</th>
<th>D#2</th>
<th>H#2</th>
```

I totally understand why I am getting duplicates like that - I'm not sure how to avoid that though. It's like I need to do this:

```
...
<th>Name</th>

        @foreach($athlete->kickoffs as $key=>$kickoff)
            <th>D#{{ ($key+1) }}</th>
            <th>H#{{ ($key+1) }}</th>
        @endforeach

<th>Avg. Distance</th>
...
```

That way I only get this output:

```
<th>D#1</th>
<th>H#1</th>
<th>D#2</th>
<th>H#2</th>
```

But I can't access the `$athlete` variable directly like that.

Comment: Create a header list which is in the order you want them to be in and iterate over that for your headers. You can then use that array to iterate on each row for the athlete and access the keys in the same order:
`foreach ($columns as $column) echo $athlete->{$column};

Comment: Well, I didn't quite use your solution - but it did trigger a thought which lead me to a solution so thank you!

Comment: glad I could help @damon.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with so that my table header would only render once no matter how many athletes I have.

**my-view.blade.php**

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
@foreach($camp->athletes as $athlete)
    @foreach($athlete->kickoffs as $key=>$kickoff)
        @if(($key+1) > $i)
            <th>D#{{ ($key+1) }}</th>
            <th>H#{{ ($key+1) }}</th>
            <?php $i++; ?>
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```